# The X of which vs. with an X that

Tags: relative-clauses, whose

Is there is any guideline to decide which of the following structures is preferred in written American English in scientific papers? The sentences below are just some examples.

Example 1:

Structure 1: **, the X of which**

This function has an input parameter, **the value of which** needs to be integer.

Structure 2: **with an X that**

This function has an input parameter **with a value that** needs to be integer.

Example 2:

Structure 1: **, the X of which**

This house has several rooms, **the smallest of which** is only six square meters.

Structure 2: **with an X that**

This house has several rooms **with the smallest** being only six square meters.

Comment: All you need is "which must be an integer." An integer, not *the value* of an integer.  Yet, "the value of which" is so unnecessary it is thus a boon to academic writing, *the value of which* is raised by word and sentence length, and lowered by simplicity.

Comment: The second structure may be misinterpreted as a function, accepting some parameter AND an integer value

Comment: Ok, you are right. Well, may be my example is a bad example because the sentence of my example for the structure 1  is not neccessary. I just wanted to know in general whether there is a preference between structure 1 and structure 2 when both can be used.

Comment: I just added a second example to make clear what I want to know. I hope the second is a better example.

Comment: Both are grammatical. It's common to find there is more than one way to express something in English. And scientific papers aren't required to be beautiful, succinct English. Is there any reason you think one or other is ungrammatical or not to be preferred?

Comment: I asked because I have no clue about the answer to my question. If the answer is that there is not a preference for any of the two structures, I am glad to know.

Comment: This house has several rooms, *with the smallest only* six square meters. The rest does not help.

Comment: The choice is yours, there are no general guidelines for style choices like this.

Comment: These should probably all be using *whose* instead. It's much simpler that way.

Comment: @YosefBaskin No. They are not the same, at least in compsci. X may *be* something but not *have the value of* something. An uninitialized integer which has an illegal value may *be* an integer (i.e. have the type of integer) but not *have the value of* an integer.  (In the specific case of an integer it's admittedly unlikely, but in the more general case, such as a float or a pointer, it's very possible.)

Comment: *This function has an input parameter whose value must be an integer.*

Comment: @YosefBaskin, *This function has an input parameter, the value of which needs to be an integer* and *This function has an input parameter which needs to be an integer* have quite different meanings in computer programming.